# How to customize picker in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget, picker

I want to know any way I can customize picker .in android there they are giving some hints that it can be done in [here](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/pickers.html)

but I can't find any tutorial. basically, I want to create a city picker and I want to knew that is there any way to do so. I really want some consistency in my app because I m already using date and time picker and I need to create the same theme picker.

So is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution i was amazed that it was so easy and no one ever pointed it out . we just have to use a numberpicker and give the value . to get the value i have to just add a listener

```
NumberPicker n = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
        String[] a={"noman","iqbal","ikram","cheema"};
        n.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        n.setDisplayedValues(a);
        n.setMaxValue(3);
        n.setMinValue(0);
        n.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

                Log.e(null, newVal+"");


            }
        });
```

when i was showing some value it was continuously showing the softkeyboard  just add

```
 n.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

this line so keyboard is not showing any more.